# react-route-dom - how can I know if history push didn't succeed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a functionaly on my react application that when I click a button, it must cycle through all the routes on my header-menu, I did acompplished that, but some of my routes are protected(disabled on my header-menu, but still visible) and the user will not have access to them. I using the function below to change routes whenever a user click on the "change route button", but If a route "is disabled on the menu", it doens't loop through all the items, it will loop till it reaches the route that its disabled and ignore all the items that comes after the disabled route.

```
 const changeRoute = e => {
    e.preventDefault()

    // each route represents an item in my header menu
    // when the user clicks a button, it will change the route following the array
    const routes = [
      '/route1',
      '/route2',
      '/route3',
      '/route4',
      '/route5',
      '/route6'
    ]
    const currentRoute = window.location.pathname
    const currentIndex = routes.indexOf(currentRoute)
    const nextIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % routes.length

    history.push(routes[nextIndex])
  }
```

If all the routes all enabled for the user, the user can cycle through all of them without a problem, but for example, if route 3 is disabled, the code will loop through route 1 and 2, and ignore the rest. I don't know if its possible to know if `history.push` knows when a route push was not concluded. If its not succeed it must follow the next route from the array.

Other solution that I was thinking it's to read the dom of the menu and check, what items are enabled, so I can cycle through them.

Comment: What does "enabled route" mean? Is your question rather, "How can I programmatically know I can navigate to a route?" What is wrong with cycling through all the routes, protected or not? Is there an issue if said user hits a protected route and they are not authenticated and are redirected to log in to access that route? Couldn't you just check auth conditions along with the route being "protected" and deduce it's access? Would an optimal solution be to only cycle through publicly accessible routes? [mcve].

Comment: all the routes are protected, but users can have different levels of permissions, and all the items are visible to them(enabled/disabled) from the menu

Comment: Ether way, `history.push` will have succeeded if installed correctly.  Keep in mind that `indexOf` returns "-1" if the route is not found, so it seems you have no contigency for that.

Comment: I mean, I guess if the code has the routes and knows the permission levels, and it has a user and their permission level, it should be able to figure out what is reachable and navigate. The only way I see `history.push` failing is if you pass it an invalid argument or pass it a target path that you are not rendering a route for. It seems like what you really want is to know if the app *can* navigate, not if it was successful after the fact.

Comment: I used another approach, I just separated the 2 logics, I stored all the permitted routes for that user in another function, so when I loop through the array, I'll know previosiosly which route the user can access without the need to use history to know which route is working